# How to dynamically add and remove table rows and add/update them to the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor-pages

I'm working on a project that includes Asp.net Core, Entity Framework and Razor pages. I want to be able to click on an add button and show more table rows that i can fill and update/add to the database.

At this moment there is one table row and if i save it it will add or update to the database. The thing i cant figure out is how to dynamicly add more table rows and add/update them to the database aswell.

We have found a workaround by using an API call and using vue.js but this seems unneeded and there should be an easier way right?

The examples below don't work...

```
<tbody>
                                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.BookingModel.HourRows.Count; i++)
                                {
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a class="btn-remove-time-row" v-on:click="removeHourRow(index)"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></td>
                                    <td class="has-text-input" style="display:none;"><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Werksoort" asp-for="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Id" value="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Id" readonly style="display:none;"/></td>
                                    <td class="has-text-input"><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Werksoort" asp-for="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].WorkTypeId" value="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].WorkTypeId" /></td>
                                    <td class="has-text-input"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Project" asp-for="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].ProjectId" value="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].ProjectId" /></td>
                                    <td class="has-text-input"><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="0,00" asp-for="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Monday" value="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Monday" /></td>
                                    <td class="has-text-input"><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="0,00" asp-for="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Tuesday" value="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Tuesday" /></td>
                                    <td class="has-text-input"><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="0,00" asp-for="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Wednesday" value="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Wednesday" /></td>
                                    <td class="has-text-input"><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="0,00" asp-for="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Thursday" value="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Thursday" /></td>
                                    <td class="has-text-input"><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="0,00" asp-for="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Friday" value="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Friday" /></td>
                                    <td class="has-text-input"><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="0,00" asp-for="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Saturday" value="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Saturday" /></td>
                                    <td class="has-text-input"><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="0,00" asp-for="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Sunday" value="@Model.BookingModel.HourRows[i].Sunday" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                }


                                <tr class="times-row-control">
                                    <td colspan="11">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-add-time-row" id="addBtn" v-on:click="addHourRow()"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Regel toevoegen</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
```

```
addHourRow: function () {
                data.booking.hourRows.push({
                    workTypeId: undefined,
                    projectId: undefined,
                    monday: undefined,
                    tuesday: undefined,
                    wednesday: undefined,
                    thursday: undefined,
                    friday: undefined,
                    saturday: undefined,
                    sunday: undefined
                })
            }
```

I expect a button which will add a tabelrow to the table and if i fill everything in i expect it to be added or updated to the database.

Answer (score 0):

As you observed, the function `addHourRow` adds data to a data structure (I can't see what kind) in the browser's page state, but doesn't do anything to change the data at its source, in your database.

To update the database, you'll need to add a request handler to a [controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions?view=aspnetcore-2.2), and call the controller from your javascript code.

This video tutorial of Entity Framework may be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZX7_12fwQLU

Comment: I think i wasnt clear enough the adding to the database work. I want to dynamically add html table rows with java.

Comment: I see.  I think this is a vue.js question then, and I don't know vue.js. :-(